# Dict containing keys with lists of lists

Tags: python

I have a dict structured as below:

```
{ 'records':[['15','2013-04-02','Mexico','blah','bleh',1,2],['25','2013-04-02','Italy','meh','heh',3,4]], 'attributes':['id','date','location','descr1','descr2','total1','total2'] }
```

It was created from json using json.load.

How can I iterate through the records key as to make ['records'][0] a key in a new dict and the remainder of each list in ['records'] be the value for that key.

Something like this is what I am thinking, may not even be possible, I am new to Python:

```
{ '15':['2013-04-02','Mexico','blah','bleh',1,2], '25':['2013-04-02','Italy','meh','heh',3,4] }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to going about iterating through the original dict to create the new one?

Comment: do you want the value to be a `list`, or a string representation of a list?

Comment: Please specify a correct output, this is invalid : `'['2013-04-02','Italy','meh','heh',3,4]`

Comment: I am pretty sure a list, I am going to want to access the contents of those lists with their indexes.  I fixed the output too, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rec_lsts = orgi_dict['records']
new_dict = {}
for l_list in rec_lsts:
    new_dict[l_lst[0]] = l_lst[1:]
```

Answer (score 7):

If `d` is your dictionary:

```
In [5]: {rec[0]:rec[1:] for rec in d['records']}
Out[5]: 
{'15': ['2013-04-02', 'Mexico', 'blah', 'bleh', 1, 2],
 '25': ['2013-04-02', 'Italy', 'meh', 'heh', 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = { 'records':[['15','2013-04-02','Mexico','blah','bleh',1,2], ['25','2013-04-02','Italy','meh','heh',3,4]], 'attributes':['id','date','location','descr1','descr2','total1','total2']}

new_d = {}

for a in d['records']:
    new_d[a[0]] = a[1:]

print new_d
```